# Accessing to properties using dot notation in React throws me an error

Tags: reactjs, object, properties, fetch

I'm trying to access to a json object using dot notation but it throws me an error. Here's my code: https://codepen.io/manAbl/pen/aGymRg?editors=0110

I'm destructuring like this: `const { weather } = this.state;`

And when I do: `console.log(weather)` It shows me the hole json object, just fine but when I try to do `console.log(weather.name)` the console throws me an error

What am I doing wrong? I must be missing something easy but I can't see it and I'm stuck

I want to be able to access the properties and set them as a value on my state, so I can them write some functions to display an icon depending on what is the current weather of the location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.state.weather` is `null` initially (before the `setState` in `componentDidMount` is called), so you need to check if it's not null first before accessing the properties.

Alternatively, set `weather` to `{}` instead of `null` initially.

Comment: ...or check it via ```console.log(weather ? weather.name : "weather is not set")```

Comment: Thanks! the issue was because I was trying  to access the properties before the api call so I was getting null back and that caused the error

Answer (score 0):

You initialize your state like this :

```
this.state = {
  weather: null,
  loading: true,
};
```

Then you're updating the `weather` var in your `componentDidMount`

`componentDidMount` is fired after the `render` method is called

So the 1st time the `render` method is called, your `weather` var is `null` and filled after `componentDidMount` is called

You should do

```
this.state = {
  weather: {},
  loading: true,
};
```

or check if your var isn't `null`